# emscripten document.createElement in C

Tags: javascript, emscripten

Inside my C code that will be compiled by Emscripten
How do I create an HTML element?
There is this emscripten function
`emscripten_request_pointerlock` that requires a `Target HTML element id`
How can I get this id after creating an HTML element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `target` argument of `emscripten_request_pointerlock`is described in the Emscripten documentation [here](https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/api_reference/html5.h.html#registration-functions). If you pass a value of `0` it will apply to the default canvas element of Emscripten.
If you want it to apply to some other element you can just pass the id of that element as a string. Presumably if you're creating the HTML element you will have control over what its id is, so just pass that.

Comment: what about creating an html element in the C code. is this the only way? `EM_ASM({ document.createElement("canvas"); });`

Comment: You can create an HTML element any way you would normally, so either include it in the HTML document initially, or create it with JavaScript (not necessarily in an `EM_ASM` block like you have here but you can if you want).